# Printing largest prime factor of a composite number

Tags: c, primes

I want the output to be like this:

```
6857
1471
839
71
```

But I am getting the numbers that are not even the factors of 600851475143.

What is wrong with this code?

The output should be all prime numbers and their product must be equal to 600851475143.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int temp;
void fact(long a);
int prime(int a);

int main(){ 
    fact(600851475143);
}

void fact(long num){
    for(int i=2; i<sqrt(600851475143); i++){
        if(num%i == 0){
            if(prime(i)){
                printf("%d\n", i);  
                temp=num/i;
                fact(temp);
            }   
        }
    }
}

int prime(int num){

    for(int i=2; i<num; i++){

        if(num % i == 0){
            break;
        }else{
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C != C++. Only tag with you are actually using.

Comment: Some compilers might need the suffix `L` as in `600851475143L`.

Comment: I think `prime` is incorrect. Do not return a normal value when `break` is done. `return i;` is too early to judge. Also I think that `long long` should be used instead of `long` as a whole (Including numeric literals.).

Comment: and after the recursive call you probably want to return from function.

Comment: 600851475143 is a 40-bit number.  I think most machines still implement plain `long` as 32 bits.  Try using `long long`.

Comment: Why is `temp` a global variable?  That seems very strange.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this recursively?  It makes it much harder to think about, and I don't see any advantage to it.

Comment: @SteveSummit it's what the prof/TA insisted on.

Comment: I suppose the recursive structure is: "1. Find candidate factor `i`. 2. Divide `i` out of the `num` being factored: `num = num / i`. 3: Recursively call `fact()` to factor the new, smaller `num`." The problem is that the recursive call probably starts over with 2 as the first candidate factor in the process of finding `i`, which is inefficient if we've already removed all the 2's from `num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number whose factor you are trying to find is out of the range of values that long can hold.[Here you can see maximum size of values that data type in c can store](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-data-types/).Also, I would recommend using **long long** at all places where the number to be stored is derived from the **num** i.e. in your program everywhere.Make sure not to change data types unless you are sure that it won't cross its maximum limit.
Also, how can you use

```
for(int i=2; i<sqrt(600851475143); i++)
```

in C code?Thats the C++ feature.
Also, there is no need for

```
#include <time.h>
```

so your code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <time.h>

int temp;
void fact(long long a);
long long prime(long long a);

int main(){
    fact(600851475143);
}

void fact(long long num){
    long long i=2;
    for(; i<sqrt(600851475143); i++){
        if(num%i == 0){
            if(prime(i)){
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
}

long long prime(long long num){
    long long i=2;
    int k = 1;
    for(; i<num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            k=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It gives the output: 
71
839
1471
6857
59569
104441
486847
But I want only upto 6857 so that the product (71*839*1471*6857) is equal to 600851475143.

Comment: @RhitikPokharel I modifies the code.Please have a look.